# How to add borders to tabulator-bulma.css?

Tags: css, tabulator

I am unable to add borders to the tabulator table using the tabulator 4.2.3 css file.

I've tried changing the -is-bordered classes but the displayed table show no border.  I find the Bulma theme pleasing but need borders to make it more table and data entry friendly for my users.

CSS section referenced below:

```
 .tabulator.is-bordered {
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

 .tabulator.is-bordered .tabulator-header .tabulator-col {
      border-right: 1px solid black;
    }

 .tabulator.is-bordered .tabulator-tableHolder .tabulator-table 
 .tabulator-row .tabulator-cell {
      border-right: 1px solid black;
     }
```

I thought I would have 1px Black border around each cell and header, but it still shows as no border.

Comment: did you mark it as important?

Answer (score 0):

The ***is-bordered*** class is working in v 4.4.3.

Are you sure you are only including the `tabulator_bulma.css`. if you include the `tabulator.css` as well the two will fight against each other.